# Relating a Date Slicer from a different table for Filtering in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Currently, I have about three tables in my Power BI report. 
1. First table lists retailer records for the year 2016. (Columns: CompanyID, Company, FullAddres, Status). So this would list records for the year 2016 from January 1st to december 31st
2. Second table is same as above but for the year 2017.
3. Third one is a Date Table I have created in sql server and then loaded in the power Bi.

I created visualizations along with some calculated measures. The goal is to use the DateTable as a slicer and upon filtering the Week Ending date in the slicer it should reflect the results. so basically DateTable has week ending date as a column and using which we  i want to filter the results.

I have created Relationship of Date Table with other two tables but unfortunately when i filter, it doesn't work fine. Kind of results in 0 results.

The relationship of DateTable with both the tables is created as Many to one with cross filter direction set to both.(tried with single as well)

How should i make some changes so that i can use WeekEnding Date from DateTable as a slicer? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What column in table1 and table2 are you using in your relationship? Also, how are you supposed to know what data from table1 and table2 go with a particular week ending if there is no column in those tables to specify it?

Comment: Sorry a little mistake in stating columns for first two tables: Both tables contain MemberStatus Date as a date column so i have relationship between MemberStatusDate of  first two tables with WeekEnding Date of Date table.

Comment: Check all the date columns have a consistent Data Type.

Comment: Hi , I came across a similar scenario once when a slicer wasn't working properly with a measure. I would recommend to remove that measure and see if the slicer works properly now , if it does , then it means there is a problem with your measure. for which you can provide further details in the question.

Comment: Measures reflect the data fine when i use the Member Status date column from the First two tables and use it as slicer. MemberStatusDate is a common column for first two tables and if i use that as a slicer, it just works fine.The problem occurs when i use the Week Ending date from Date Table as a slicer. The date table has been created in the sql server and imported into power bi from there to integrate it with other two tables. I have defined relationship of Week Ending Date of date table to MemberStatusDate of other two tables. Still when i use MemberStatusDate as a slicer, it doesn't work

Comment: try not using two tables (one for 2016 and one for 2017). Create a custom column in the 2016 table and call it as year with value of 2016 and do the same for 2017 table and call it as year with value of 2017. Once you have all the column names common in both the tables. you should be able to append them. While Appending Append them as new table (call it as Final_Table) and connect this new table to the DateTable that you have. This shall work. I have used it this way in my projects.